# Rails parameters error - Implementing Google Maps API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently building an Events app using Rails.I'm implementing the Google Maps Embed API for the Events show page and getting the following error -

"The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Missing the 'q' parameter."

I have the Geocoder gem installed, included latitude & longitude. For my address I'm using a 'location' column and use jquery.autocomplete for that purpose. This is my code for the showpage -

```
 <h3>Location</h3>
                <p><%= @event.location %></p>
                <iframe
                        width="600"
                        height="450"
                            frameborder="0" style="border:0"
                    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=<%= ENV["google_maps_api_key"] %>=<%= @event.location %>" allowfullscreen>
                </iframe>
```

Do I still need a specific method for the address in my events model to fix this? If so, how do I express that in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

There's a small error in your google maps URI (as per the error message), try this as the src attribute:

```
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=<%= ENV["google_maps_api_key"] %>&q=<%= @event.location %>" allowfullscreen>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm now getting this error - "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This service requires an API key." My api key is in my secrets.yml file - have I made an error with the hash above?

Comment: When you use  `ENV["google_maps_api_key"]`, Rails looks for an environment variable named `google_maps_api_key`, which will be `nil`, as it isn't set. Secrets from you secrets.yml file can be accessed through, for example, `Rails.application.secrets.google_maps_api_key`. This will look up the secret for the current RAILS_ENV.